# Why is GlueStudio not seeing same script as legacy jobs view in AWS console?

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

When I update my script in S3 (Script path) and open Glue Studio, I do not see the updates for this script (pyspark). But if I open the legacy jobs, it has the latest code. What is also odd, if I look at Job details IN glue studio, I see the updated --additional-python-modules. Our code is deployed through Ansible Tower. One other thing is if you are in GlueStudio and you "Run" the script, it will run the latest code. So issue is with the editor not having latest code.

Answer (score 0):

This had to do something with security. I had completely logged off and back on, clearing all caches and was able to see updates in studio. Seems like a bug but past this issue.